# Proved $|B|=2+\frac{C_{2p}^{p}-2}{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}=\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,2p-1\right\}$.
> Let $$B=\left\{A\subset\mathbb{Z}_{2p}: 
>   |A|=p\;\; \wedge \;\;\displaystyle\sum_{k\in A}{}k=0\pmod p\right\}$$
> Prove that: $\quad |B|=2+\frac{C_{2p}^{p}-2}{p}$

This question was suggested to me by my friend after trying to solve it, but I did not reach any results after several attempts. Is there any idea or suggestion for how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance..

Comment: This is similar to **IMO 1995 P6** and **Nikolay Nikolov** won a special prize for his marvellous solution using $p^{th}$ roots of unity.

Comment: What is $C_{2p}$? I don't see it defined anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let define:

- $S$ be the set of all subsets $A\subseteq\Bbb Z_{2p}$ such that $|A|=p$;

  $U=\{2k:0\leq k<p\}$ and $V=\{2k+1:0\leq k<p\}$;

  $T=S\setminus\{U,V\}$.

  for every $n\in\Bbb Z_p$ let
  \begin{align}
  S_n&=\{A\in S:\sum_{k\in A}k\equiv n\pmod p\}\\
  T_n&=\{A\in T:\sum_{k\in A}k\equiv n\pmod p\}
  \end{align}

Then these steps leads to prove your statement:

1. $|S|=\binom{2p}p$;

   $U,V\in S_0$;

   $|T|=\binom{2p}p-2$;

   For every $A\in T$ there exists the smallest $c\in A$ such that
   \begin{align}
   \exists h\in A(h\equiv c-1\pmod p)\\
   \nexists k\in A(k\equiv c+1\pmod p)
   \end{align}
   and we define $A'=(A\setminus\{h\})\cup\{k\}$;

   The function $A\mapsto A'$ is injective and maps $T_n\to T_m$ whenever $m\equiv n+2\pmod p$;

   $|T_n|=|T_m|$ for every $n,m\in\Bbb Z_p$;

   $|T|=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z_p}|T_n|$;

   $|T_n|=(\binom{2p}p-2)/p$;

   $|S_0|=2+(\binom{2p}p-2)/p$;